# How to disable Action bar tab for fragments?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

As i am using Action bar 3 tabs with fragments A,B,C want to disable B,C initially i am using

```
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = ab.newTab();
    tab2.setText("PORT");
    tab2.setTabListener(this);
    tab2.setEnable(false);
```

but not allows me to use tab2.setEnable 
what is exact way to disable it?

Comment: There is no "enable" or "disable" with tabs in the action bar. As far I know, you can remove and re-add them.

Comment: are you sure @amit singh

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove a tab from the actionbar. Enable or disableing tabs is not supported. There is also no visibility function for tabs. You have to call:

```
ab.removeTab(tab2);
```

to [remove a tab](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#removeTab%28android.app.ActionBar.Tab%29) from the actionbar. But that does not require that you have to destroy (`tab2 = null`) your tab.

Comment: if i want to use Enable or disableing functions in my application what is alternative for action bar Tabs? I can achieve it with TabActivity over FragmentActivity but TabActivity  is depricated frm API 13