# How to enable / disable individual tabs in Action Bar Tabs programmatically

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

Am using Tab Swipes - ActionBar Tabs with 3 tabs. Would like to programmatically enable and disable individual tabs. If enabling / disabling is complex, then at least I should be able to show and hide individual tabs. How to achieve this

To elaborate, While on Tab 1, I want to preferable disable / (if not possible at least hide) Tab 2 and Tab 3. Only after I finish with Tab 1, I should be able to proceed to Tab 2 through a press of a custom button and while on Tab 2, I should not be able to select Tab 1 and Tab 3 and so on. Of course, once I complete with this sequential progression, I would like to enable /show all the tabs.

After typing this, I saw this question being asked here
[How to disable Action bar tab for fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305546/how-to-disable-action-bar-tab-for-fragments)

Is it true we cannot have handle on individual tabs, programmatically?

Comment: Note that action bar tabs are deprecated as of Android 5.0.

Comment: what is their replacement? And, will that work for Android 4.0 with the use of any support libraries?       If my target audience uses Android 4.0,what is the way out?

Comment: "what is their replacement?" -- either another tab solution (e.g., `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip`) or another navigation solution (e.g., a nav drawer).